# Rails 3 + JQuery + Dynamic Combobox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been looking on other threads but couldn't get a example working.

I have a "groups" combobox that when I selected a value, it will change the values for the combobox "categories" when values for that selected group.

**View (show.html.erb)**

```
<%= form_for(@store_classification, :url => {:action => 'add_classification'}) do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><%= t(:newClassificationDetails) %></legend>
    <%= f.hidden_field :store_id, :value => params[:id] %>
    <div id="groups" class="fields">
      <%= f.label t(:group) %><br />
      <%= f.select :group_id,
                   options_from_collection_for_select(@groups, :id, :name),
                   :data => { :remote => true, :url => url_for(:controller => :stores,
                                                                :action => :update_categories)}%>
    </div>
    <div id="categories" class="fields">
        <%= f.label t(:category) %><br/>
        <%= f.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :id, :name) %>
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
        <%= f.submit t(:add) %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

**Partial (_categories.html.erb)**

```
<div id="categories" class="fields">
        <%= f.label t(:category) %><br/>
        <%= f.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :id, :name) %>
    </div>
```

**Controller (stores_controller.rb)**

```
def show
    @store_classification = StoreClassification.new    
    @groups = Group.all
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def update_categories
    category = Category.find(:all,
                             :conditions => ['group_id = ?',params[:selected]])
    render :partial => :categories
  end
```

**Javascript (application.js)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#groups").change(function() {
        $.ajax({url: '<%= url_for :action => :update_categories, :id => @group_id %>',
        data: 'selected=' + this.value,
        dataType: 'script'})
    });
});
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

dont know about the rails stuff you probably should have posted the html generated by it, any way attach a `change` event handler to the `groups` combo

```
$("#groupCombo").change(function(e){

  //make the ajax call to get the categories

  $.ajax({
     url:"url",
     type:"get",
     dataType:"json", //the type of response you are expecting from the server
     success:function(data){
        $("#categoryCombo").empty(); //clear the categories combo

        //iterate over the result sent by the server and populate the category combo e.g.
         $.each(data,function(k,v){
           $("#categoryCombo").append("<option>"+v+"</option>");
         });

     },
     error:function(jxhr){
         console.log(jxhr.responseText);
     }


  });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AHSHP/13/)